# Echarts: how to get x and y values during mouse events

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I have the following chart:

```js
const quotesChart = echarts.init(quotesContainer);
quotesChart.setOption({
  dataset: [
    { source: quotes }
  ],
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      position: 'left',
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Quotes',
      type: 'line',
      datasetIndex: 0,
    }
  ]
})

quotesChart.getZr().on("mousemove", function(params){
  const pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
 
  // how do I get x and y values for current mouse position?

  // I see some examples using convertFromPixel but I don't know how to use these coordinates to get x and y values
  const pointInGrid = quotesChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);
})
```

The `quotes` dataset source looks like: `[{period: '20/01/2021', value: 15.59}, {period: '21/01/2021', value: 15.99}]`

I need to get values from axis x and y (ex: `20/01/2021` and `15.59`) but I don't know how, I only have the grid coordinates.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps this read could be of help: https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought, it turns out `pointInGrid[0]` is the position of the series array, so I did: `quotes[pointInGrid[0]]` to get the series item I needed.

Answer (score 1):

let x = pointInGrid[0];

let y = pointInGrid[1];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).